# Python Bytearray Printing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an integer list in Python that should correspond to the following int values (which can be changed to hex byte values):

```
[10, 145, 140, 188, 212, 198, 210, 25, 152, 20, 120, 15, 49, 113, 33, 220, 124, 67, 174, 224, 220, 241, 241]
```

However, when I convert that list to a bytearray (using bytearray(nameOfList)), I get the following printout.

```
bytearray(b'\n\x91\x8c\xbc\xd4\xc6\xd2\x19\x98\x14x\x0f1q!\xdc|C\xae\xe0\xdc\xf1\xf1')
```

I can pull the correct values from this byte array, regardless of how it prints, but shouldn't the bytearray printout correspond to the hex values of the byte array? (I mean, it seems to mostly follow the hex values up until after \x0f, where it starts putting out gibberish...)

Comment: It looks fine to me. It's just rendering bytes as ASCII characters whenever possible. After `\x0f` you have 49='1' and 113='q', etc. http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Exactly ... It only represents non-printing characters as `\x..`

Comment: [`list(your_bytearray) == your_list`](http://ideone.com/GdLDxK)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
>>> x = bytearray(b'\n\x91\x8c\xbc\xd4\xc6\xd2\x19\x98\x14x\x0f1q!\xdc|C\xae\xe0
\xdc\xf1\xf1')
>>> import binascii
>>> print(binascii.hexlify(x))
0a918cbcd4c6d2199814780f317121dc7c43aee0dcf1f1
```

Use [binascii](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html) if you want all of it to be printed as a hex string

Comment: ...just what I needed.

Answer (score 20):

Use bytes.hex()

```
>>> x = bytearray([0x01,0x02,0xff])
>>> print(x.hex())
0102ff
```

Comment: This is so much better.

Answer (score 12):

It looks fine to me. It's just rendering bytes as ASCII characters whenever possible. After 15=`\x0f` you have 49='1' and 113='q', etc.

See http://asciitable.com

Comment: Is there any way to switch this behavior off? It's so annoying when you are working with binary data.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not very performant at large sizes, but I find this makes it easier to read:

```py
buff = bytearray(list(range(10)))
print(buff)
print(", ".join(hex(b) for b in buff))
```

prints

```py
bytearray(b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t')
0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9
```