# Why is this first Byte printed as (b'c\x..) instead of (b'x63\x..)?

Tags: python, arrays, printing, hex, byte

I am writing a program for padding oracle attacks and need `bytearrays`,
but if I define a new `bytearray` the first byte `0x63` gets printed different.

I have to `XOR` 2 `bytearrays` bytewise.

```
test = bytearray( [99,203,00] )
print(test)
print(hex(99))
```

Output:

```
bytearray(b'c\xcb\x00')
0x63
```

This is my first question here. Thanks for your help!

[image: f]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add you code to the question, so that people who want to help you can copy-paste it to their IDE. Pictures are not so helpful

Comment: might be a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093700/python-bytearray-printing - but its not a 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For string output python replaces printable hexcodes by the `chr(hexcode)` character for display purposes:

```
print('c', ord('c'),hex(ord('c')))   #  c 99 '0x63'

t = bytearray([99,203,0])
print(t)                             #  bytearray(b'c\xcb\x00')
print(t[0],t[1],t[2])                #  99 203 0
```

They are equivalent - but shorter to print out. You can get a all-hex representation like so:

```
t = bytearray([99,203,0])
t_hex = '\\'+'\\'.join( ( hex(i) for i in t) ) 

print(t_hex)
```

Output:

```
\0x63\0xcb\0x0
```

Comment: is there a way that i can print '63' instead of '0x63' ?

Comment: @R.K. you can slice the 0x away:  `t_hex = ''.join( ( hex(i)[2:] for i in t) )`