# How to get file contents as a binary text in Python?

Tags: python, file, binary

I am trying to make file2binary
Here's my code:

```py
with open("myfile.txt","rb") as fp:
    print(fp.read())
```

But it returns this:

```
b'helloworld'
```

And that's what I don't want
Anyway, there's a way to open the file as binary?

Comment: What is the output you expect?

Comment: It outputs `b'helloworld'`.

Comment: If you want to see the binary data represented as hex or as a list of integer bytes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093700/python-bytearray-printing?rq=3

Comment: @Kirill and what is wrong with this output? What output do you want?

Comment: I want to it return something like `01101000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 01110111 01101111 01110010 01101100 01100100`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, you want to see each byte represented as base-2 digits.

You can do something like this. The key ingredients are:

1. `f.read()` on a file opened in binary mode returns a `bytes` object, which behaves as an iterable sequence of bytes ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes)).
2. Using an f-string with the `{  :08b}` format specifier is a convenient way to output a byte as a string of bits.

```
import os
import tempfile

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
    filename = os.path.join(temp_dir, "hello.bin")
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        f.write("helloworld".encode("utf-8"))

    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        bytes_data = f.read()

for byte in bytes_data:
    print(f"{byte:08b}", end=" ")
```

Output:

```
01101000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 01110111 01101111 01110010 01101100 01100100
```